# Need help understanding precedence

Tags: grammar, operator-precedence

Can someone give me a brief description of how to determine the precedence of one thing with respect to another in a grammar? I can't seem to find a good answer in my books or online even though i'm pretty sure its very simple. Example

```
S-> B
B-> B and T | T
T-> T or F | F
F-> not F| (B)|true|false
```

The question was "what is the precedence of "and" with respect to "or" in the above grammar?".

"and" has lower precedence than "or", but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol `B` represents the `and` statement, and its definition contains `T` which is the `or`.  You can get from `and` to `or`, but not the other way around.  So if you think of the language statement as a stack, you'll keep doing replacements and adding to the top of the stack until you wind up evaluating the whole statement, and as you then pop items off you'll reverse direction and the `or` statement will always be above (and therefore evaluate before) the `and`.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think i understand. Could you just clarify this to make sure? If there was an or on the B line, or still has higher precedence. If the or was on B but not on T however, they would have the same. Is this correct?

Comment: @John -- if you put an 'or' into the B rule, the grammar becomes ambiguous, so the precedence is undefined by the grammar.  If you get rid of the T rule and put 'and' and 'or' both in the B rule, then they have the same precedence.